# MacOS: SwiftUI: NavigationView: Three Views not working properly - Buttons are duplicated, missing or flickering

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to replicate the basic layout of the Notes App of Big Sur in SwiftUI.

On Startup everything seems fine:

[To Startup Screenshot](https://ibb.co/LDKsC2Z)

On click on a sidebar Item the toolbar in the second column changes and the Button is now duplicated:

[Link SidebarItem Clicked Screenshot](https://ibb.co/bXJstND)

On click on a second bar Item the same happens in the third column:

[Link SecondColumn Item Clicked Screenshot](https://ibb.co/fCFTR9Q)

Often the toolbar Buttons are flickering or sometimes they are gone completely.

This is how i did it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView()
            ListView()
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}

struct SidebarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink("Item 1", destination: ListView())
            NavigationLink("Item 2", destination: ListView())
            NavigationLink("Item 3", destination: ListView())
            NavigationLink("Item 4", destination: ListView())
        }.toolbar {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }.frame(alignment: .trailing)
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink("List item 1", destination: DetailView())
            NavigationLink("List item 2", destination: DetailView())
            NavigationLink("List item 3", destination: DetailView())
            NavigationLink("List item 4", destination: DetailView())
        }.toolbar {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "minus")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail").toolbar {
            Button(action: {}) {
                Image(systemName: "person")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see this with Big Sur 11.2 Beta 1 and Xcode 12.3. What versions are you using?

Comment: Big Sur 11.0.1 - Xcode 12.3

Comment: Maybe it was fixed in 11.1? macOS 11.1 fixed a lot of SwiftUI bugs, it’s worth upgrading (and setting 11.1 as your app’s min target).

Comment: Thank you for the tipp i'll try that tomorrow and let you now if it works.

Comment: This seemes to fix the issues with the duplicated buttons. That's great thank you. :-)
The flickering is still there but that's not that bad.

Is the code i posted ok? Or is there something that could be done better?

Comment: Code looks fine to me. I see the same flickering issue, which seems to be an OS bug.